# Several groups of bar charts on one plot, with different size of groups. Can't align properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I can't find a way to properly align a bar chart with 3 groups of bars, each one has 1, 2, and 3 bars. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xticklabels={Lodging,,, Ridesharing, , Freelancing},
    xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.25cm},
    enlarge y limits=0,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=32,
    ytick={0,10,20,30},
    nodes near coords,
    visualization depends on={meta < 4 \as \valueissmall},
    every node near coord/.append style={
            anchor={\ifdim\valueissmall pt=1 pt south\else north\fi},
            {\ifdim\valueissmall pt=1 pt black\else white\fi}
        },
    ybar=-6pt,
    bar width=13pt,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {(1, 27)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray,bar shift=30pt] coordinates {(2, 10)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray,bar shift=20pt] coordinates {(3, 5)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray,bar shift=37pt] coordinates {(4, 3)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray,bar shift=27pt] coordinates {(5, 2)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {(6, 1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you're overcomplicating things a bit.

Instead of the `bar shift`s, it might be easier to use the x-coordinate. That is, set the first bar at x=1, the second and third at x=3 and 4, the last three at x=6,7,8.

That in turn makes it easy to place the ticklabels. Use `xtick={1,3.5,7}`, i.e. ticks at the centers of each bar group, and then `xticklabels={Lodging,Ridesharing,Freelancing}`, i.e. no empty labels. And the `xshift` in the ticklabel style is not necessary then.

Instead of multiple `\addplot`s, use just one `\addplot`, and there's no need to have `ybar` in the `\addplot` options.

For the labels above the bars, you can add the platform names as meta information directly in the coordinate stream, e.g. `(1, 27) [AirBnb]`. Then you add `visualization depends on={y \as \yvalue}`, and change the `nodes near coords` to `nodes near coords={\pgfplotspointmeta\\\pgfmathprintnumber{\yvalue}}`. In order to have the line break (`\\`) work you need `align=center` in the style of the `nodes near coords`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={1,3.5,7},
    xticklabels={Lodging,Ridesharing,Freelancing},
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=32,
    ytick={0,10,20,30},
    nodes near coords={\pgfplotspointmeta\\\pgfmathprintnumber{\yvalue}},
    visualization depends on={y \as \yvalue},
    every node near coord/.append style={
      align=center,
      },
    ybar,
    bar width=13pt,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    ]
    \addplot[fill=gray, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
       (1, 27) [AirBnb]
       (3, 10) [Uber]
       (4, 5) [Lyft]
       (6, 3) [Taskrabbit]
       (7, 2) [Upwork]
       (8, 1) [Frkrldjnrj]
       };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't try doing the rotating for the last three. They might be a bit close, I can have a look at the rotation if you want.